# How to mock nested function?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I would like to mock some nested functions from a specific function:

```py
# tools.py
def cpu_count():
    def get_cpu_quota():
        return int(load("/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpu.cfs_quota_us"))

    def get_cpu_period():
        return int(load("/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpu.cfs_period_us"))

    def get_cpus():
        try:
            cfs_quota_us = get_cpu_quota()
            cfs_period_us = get_cpu_period()
            if cfs_quota_us > 0 and cfs_period_us > 0:
                return int(math.ceil(cfs_quota_us / cfs_period_us))
        except:
            pass
        return multiprocessing.cpu_count()

    return get_cpus()
```

```py
# test_tools.py
class TestTools(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("tools.cpu_count")
    def test_cpu_count_in_container(self, cpu_count_mock):
        cpu_count_mock.return_value.get_cpu_quota.return_value = 5000
        cpu_count_mock.return_value.get_cpu_period.return_value = 1000

        cpus = tools.cpu_count()
        self.assertEqual(5, cpus)
```

However, when running this test I have the follow error:

```
FAIL: test_cpu_count_in_container (tests.util.tools_test.ToolsTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/uilian/Development/foo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1305, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "/home/uilian/Development/foo/tests/util/tools_test.py", line 154, in test_cpu_count_in_container
    self.assertIsInstance(cpus, int)
AssertionError: <MagicMock name='cpu_count()' id='140490818322384'> is not an instance of <class 'int'>
```

Is it possible mocking nested functions?

If not, what's the best approach for this case?

Comment: You can not mock a nested function, simply because it does not exist before the outer function is called. You should "un-nest" them.

Comment: "because it does not exist before the outer function is called". I think it was the answer that I was looking for. Thanks!